# TypeScript - rejected promise is not caught with .catch()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have a function that I call in the config phase of each protected view in a web app:

```
tryAuthenticate(): angular.IPromise <void> {
    debugger;
    var tokenValue = this._getCachedToken();
    var promise = this.$q.reject();

    // Some stuff with tokenValue to grab promise if user exists

    promise['catch'](() => {
        this._defaultFailedAuthenticatedAction();
    });

    return promise;
}
```

The issue is that when I visit the protected view, `tryAuthenticate()` is called and yet the `promise['catch']` function skips, so the `_defaultFailedAuthenticatedAction()` method is never called.

For a little more context here's are a couple of screenshots of my debugger as I step through.

As it hits the catch statement:

[image: As it hits the catch]

Immediately after the catch is hit:

[image: Immediately after the catch is hit]

Why isn't my code block executing? [As per Mozilla's documentation on Promises this *should* work!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)

Comment: It shouldn't matter if the promise has already been rejected, `.catch()` should get triggered (similar to `Promise.reject().catch(...)`). Is the `.catch()` _never_ called, or do you think it's not because of what the debugger shows? It may be called during the next "tick", perhaps?

Comment: @robertklep, thanks for clarifying that. The `.catch()` is _never_ called, it's quite bizarre. Ultimately what happens in this scenario is the promise is returned (as a reject), which returns to my `resolve()` function (in the view controller's config) and thus the view never loads and the app essentially crashes.

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with Angular or TS, but can you move the `.catch()` to the place where `tryAuthenticate()` gets called? `tryAuthenticate().catch(...)`